# I want to Override the customer filter over setQuickFilter

Tags: angular, ag-grid

By default Ag Grid Quick Filter function return rows that contains search string. After that How can I use setGridData?

As simple as possible

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.